# Using a filter to compare arrays and only return unique results

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm retrieving 2 JSON arrays from a remote source. I'm trying to filter the results from array X to array Y and only return the unique values from both. All of the questions on stackoverflow are for filtering 1 array not a set of multiple.

Comment: So u should write your own js function...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to `unique` filter from the [a8m/angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter'])
    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.first = [{id: 1, name:'first'},{id: 2, name:'second'}, 
{id: 3, name:'third'}, {id: 4, name: 'fourth'} ];

        $scope.second = [{id: 1, name:'first'},{id: 2, name:'second'}, 
{id: 5, name: 'fifth'} ];
      }
    ]);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.1/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in first.concat(second) | unique:'id'">
        {{item.id}} : {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```